# Tkinter bind click only on canvas not on objects

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have a code:

```
canvas.tag_bind(stvorec, '<Button-1>', clicked)
canvas.bind('<Button-1>', fail)
```

but my problem is that when I click the rectangle (the tag_bind) it also triggers the second bind on canvas. Which I don't want, because I need to do something like when clicked on rectangle score increment, when clicked outside of rectangle score decrement.

Answer (score 2):

Then you can use only `.bind()` and check whether a canvas item is clicked or not inside the bind callback:

```py
score = 0

def fail(event):
    global score
    # get ID of "current" item using .find_withtag()
    if canvas.find_withtag("current"):
        # a canvas item is clicked
        score += 1
    else:
        score -= 1

...

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", fail)
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you could also try using a flag

```py
from tkinter import *

class Score:
    def __init__(self):
        self.score=0
        self.item_clicked=False

    def canvas(self,event):
        if not self.item_clicked:
            self.score-=1
        else:
            self.score+=1
            self.item_clicked=False
        print(self.score)

    def item(self,event):
        self.item_clicked=True

    def get(self):
        return self.score

root=Tk()

canvas=Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

text_id=canvas.create_text(200,100,text='Hello World')

score=Score()
canvas.tag_bind(text_id,'<Button-1>',score.item)
canvas.bind('<Button-1>',score.canvas)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -2):

The first function called should return the str 'break' to stop event chain.

Comment: That was my first idea too but I have tried that and it does not work

Comment: @j_4321 Did you tried with both functions? Accordingly to the docks, the most specific will be triggered first.

Comment: Returning "break" will have no effect on bindings associated with canvas tags. From the official canvas documentation: _"If bindings have been created for a canvas window using the bind command, then they are invoked in addition to bindings created for the canvas's items using the bind widget command. The bindings for items will be invoked before any of the bindings for the window as a whole."_